# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'split': object is null or undefined

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have one web page, in firefox, chrome, ie9 and ie8 work ok, but in ie7 it give me error on load:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'split': object is null or
                                                                       undefined 

jquery.pulsate.min.js, line 2 character 300
```

and selected code in Script is :

`h="rgba("+e[0].split("(")[1]+","+e[1]+","+e[2].split(")")[0]+","+h+")"` -

from JQuery library

Also it give me another error:

```
SCRIPT16389: 

jquery-1.7.1.min.js, line 2 character 11496
```

and selected code in Script is  :

```
(a.execScript||function(b){a.eval.call(a,b)})(b)
```

anyone know why and how to solve the errors?

this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".pulsate").pulsate({color:'#c00'});
    });
```

here is code for call the library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.pulsate.min.js"></script>
```

when I comment this code it work ok

Comment: Check e[0],e[2] values seems some of them maybe empty

Comment: @user1145009 but I can't change jquery library

Comment: Can you show some of the code you are using these libraries for?

Comment: @putvande I added my code in the question

Comment: there's no point showing us lines of code in the jquery libraries; we can't debug them, and they probably aren't where your problem lies anyway.

Comment: by the way, if you're using [this library](http://kilianvalkhof.com/jquerypulsate/), it would appear that it doesn't work in IE7, so there may not be an answer for you, other than "don't use a library that doesn't work in browsers you need to support". (I can't get it working in IE8 either, but if you've managed it, well done)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Many JavaScript libraries do not handle IE9 well because it breaks with IE8 in the handling of a lot of things.

JavaScript code that sniffs for IE will fail quite frequently in IE9, unless such code is rewritten to handle IE9 specifically.

Try doing this ..
Before the JS code is updated, you should use the "`X-UA-Compatible`" meta tag to force your web page into IE8 mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;FF=3;OtherUA=4" />
```

Comment: HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=8;FF=3;OtherUA=4') ignored because document mode is already finalized. 
MyPage.aspx

Comment: try changin all my <script type="application/javascript" ... to <script type="text/javascript" just a wild guess..

Comment: I don't have code "application/javascript" only "text/javascript"

Comment: -1, the question is about IE7, so you talking about IE9 and IE8 is irrelevant. And also, your advice is terrible anyway -- you should never ever need to specify `"IE=8;FF=3;OtherUA=4"`. That's just awful.